# windows 8.1 not remembering update settings

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

Every time I turn my PC on I notice a flag in system tray with a red x which is notifying me about an issue in the Action Center.

I click this and it says `Change Windows Update setting (Important)`.

So I click this and get the option to select either `Install updates Automatically` or `let me choose`. No matter what I choose, as soon as I boot the computer again the issue returns.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Issue is similar but my issue only happens when starting the PC. Also the issue in that post did not get resolved and the user switched to a different operating system. I do not wish to do that

Comment: Regardless of what the original OP did, it's still the same problem/question (IMO anyway, take more than just my vote to close :) ).  Are you on a work computer/network?

Comment: no I am on a home PC.

Comment: This might just sound like a 'me too' but I have some machines here with the same issue on Win 7.1, the **only** fix that lasted more than 2 days has been a Repair Install.